# React native Android error: ScreenContainer is not attached under ReachRootView

Tags: android, react-native

the error occurs only on Android, on iOs it works fine. I'm using custom modal to render authNavigator (login, register, forgot-password screens). When user clicks on button, the custom modal opens.

What I tried:
1.) Tried to pass AuthNavigation as children prop
2.) Tried to render AuthNavigation directly in CustomModal instead of passing anything..

Both of these approaches work on iphone, but no success on android.

```
import { CustomModal } from "../../components/modal.component";
import { AuthNavigator } from "../../infrastructure/navigation/auth.navigator";

export const AccountScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  // Modal
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const toggleModal = () => {
    setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
  };

 

  return (
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Button
          mode="outlined"
          textColor={colorScheme === "light" ? "black" : "white"}
          onPress={toggleModal}
        >
          Get Started
        </Button>
        <CustomModal
          visible={modalVisible}
          toggleModal={toggleModal}
          // children={() => <AuthNavigator />}
        >
          {/* <AuthNavigator /> */}
        </CustomModal>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

```
export const CustomModal = ({ visible, toggleModal, children }) => {
  const { containerStyle, textStyle, colorScheme } = useTheme();

  return (
    <Modal visible={visible} transparent={true} animationType="slide">
      <ModalContainer>
        <ModalContent>
          <DragTouchableOpacity onPress={toggleModal} />
          <DragLineContainer>
            <DragLine />
          </DragLineContainer>
          {/* {children} */}
          <AuthNavigator />
        </ModalContent>
      </ModalContainer>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```